# How to convert type double to CGAffineTransform?

Tags: ios, swift

When I rotate my image view:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    imageView?.transform = newHeading.trueHeading

}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'CLLocationDirection' (aka 'Double') to type 'CGAffineTransform'

How to convert/assign it?

**UPDATE:**

Everything compiling OK, but when i run my app in simulator(i do not have any iOS devices), my imageview not rotate in true north.

Why?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var manager: CLLocationManager?
    var imageView: UIImageView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager?.delegate = self;
        manager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest


        imageView = UIImageView(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pointer"))
        self.view.addSubview(imageView!)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(newHeading.trueHeading))

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you wish to rotate the image view?

Comment: Yes @rmaddy i  want to rotate my image view when i rotate device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`trueHeading` is of type `Double` in degrees.

In order to rotate the `UIImageView`, one has to provide a transform:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading)
{
    imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(newHeading.trueHeading  * .pi / 180))
    // converting the value from degrees to radians, which CGAffineTransform expects.
}
```